# Pyspark: optimize getting proportion of df at each level of each categorical column

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, pyspark, aggregate

TLDR: I'm new to pyspark and I think I'm not being "sparky" while trying to do a bunch of aggregations.

I have a set of data for which I need to know the proportion of data at each level of each categorical column. For example if I start with the following:

```
|box|potato|country|
|1  |red   |usa    |
|1  |red   |mexico |
|1  |yellow|canada |
|1  |red   |canada |
|1  |red   |mexico |
```

I want to end up with:

```
|box|potato.red|potato.yellow|country.usa|country.mexico|country.canada|
|1  |0.80      |0.20         |0.20       |0.40          |0.40          |
```

So, my output is a dataframe with one row per dataset about my boxes of potatoes and a number of columns equal to the sum of each unique level of each categorical column (in this case 2 + 3 = 5) plus one for the dataset identifier.

I'd like to optimize my approach as actual, non-potato data, is much larger and has ~100 categorical columns with any where from 2 - 100 levels.

I think my primary problem is that while I'm implementing this in pyspark - I'm not actually being 'sparky' in how I do it. Any types on optimizing by using a more pyspark appropriate approach are appreciated.

Current approach:

```
box_of_potatos = <readindata>

sz = box_of_potatos.count()
proportion = count(*)/sz

output_for_one_box = process_potatos(box_of_potatos, 1)
        
def process_potatos(df, dataset_id):
        c_str = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t.startswith('string')]                      
        
        foo = spark.createDataFrame([Row(id = dataset_id)])                                     
        
        for i in c_str:                                                                       
            bar = categorical_lvl(df, i, dataset_id)
            foo = foo.join(bar, ['dataset_id'])                                                      
        return(foo)

 def categorical_lvl(df, cat_attribute, dataset_id):
        newCols = [cat_attribute, dataset_id]                                                      
        smry = df_demo.groupBy(cat_attribute).agg(proportion)                                      

        smry = smry.toDF(*newCols).withColumn('column_modified', f.concat(f.lit(cat_attribute), f.lit("."), f.col(cat_attribute))).withColumn('id', f.lit(dataset_id))
        smry = smry.groupBy('id').pivot('column_modified').avg(dataset_id).fillna(0)            
        
        
        return(smry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame (df):

```
+---+------+-------+
|box|potato|country|
+---+------+-------+
|  1|   red|    usa|
|  1|   red| mexico|
|  1|yellow| canada|
|  1|   red| canada|
|  1|   red| mexico|
+---+------+-------+
```

Try PySpark `pivot()` to get desired result

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count 

total_count = df.count()

# Helps in adding prefix to columns
rename_columns = lambda prefix, columns: [f"{prefix}.{column}" if column != "box" else column for column in columns]

pivot_potato = df.groupBy("box").pivot("potato").agg((count("potato") / total_count))
pivot_potato = pivot_potato.toDF(*rename_columns("potato", pivot_potato.columns))

pivot_country = df.groupBy("box").pivot("country").agg(count("country") / total_count)
pivot_country = pivot_country.toDF(*rename_columns("country", pivot_country.columns))

pivot_potato.join(pivot_country, "box", "inner").show()
```

Output

```
+---+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|box|potato.red|potato.yellow|country.canada|country.mexico|country.usa|
+---+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|  1|       0.8|          0.2|           0.4|           0.4|        0.2|
+---+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```